# Sticky header to change colour while scrolling - WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I set the navbar with no background color?

For example. If the page is scrolled to #work, The colour should be different.
If the page is scrolled to #testi, The colour should be different.

I have tried almost a dozen tutorials but I'm unable to achieve it with WordPress.

URL: http://www.clickableco.com/demo1/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manage this functionality with the below code.

```
var top1 = $('#home').offset().top;
var top2 = $('#featuredWork').offset().top;
var top3 = $('#caseStudy').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrollPos >= top1 && scrollPos < top2) {
    $('#change').css('background-color', '#f00');
  } else if (scrollPos >= top2 && scrollPos < top3) {
    $('#change').css('background-color', '#0f0');
  } else if (scrollPos >= top3) {
    $('#change').css('background-color', '#00f');
  }
});
```

You will have to find the position as per your content section.

Apply the header background color as per section scroll.

Hope this will help.

Comment: this will fire scroll event 100s of times per second

Comment: hmm..than we have to find another better way.. :) @fawmi

Comment: you should either work with window.requestAnimationFrame() or setTimeout()